# Comparing areas of overlapping shapes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatial-join, differences

Given SHP files for a country's Districts in Year1 and Year2, how to output a table whose rows state the percentage composition of each Year2 District in terms of portions of Year1 Districts

Comment: you can join the tables together and add a column to where you can calculate the percentage composition.

Comment: It is not clear to me if you are interested only in change of area of district from Year1 to Year2. Or districts are in these two years splitting / merging, added and removed. Could you please clear it up?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: At first I thought the issue was resolved, but looking again I saw things I couldn't understand, and after further attempts went to  an ArcGIS superuser who is also familiar with (an earlier version of ) QGIS.

Comment: Previous comment sent before completion - will send new comment later

Answer (score 1):

As Goldring mentionned in his comment you should probably join the 2 tables and compute the percentage, assuming of course that your districts in both years do overlap

Comment: Both Union and Intersection are returning bad results in QGIS with SHP files that work fine in ArcGIS. 
In ArcGIS, the Union of 22263 polygons (Year 1) and 22612 polygons (Year 2) – both covering the whole country) returns 24521 polygons, and the arithmetic of area is fine.
In QGIS the same Union returns a set with over million rows in the Attribute table which nevertheless omits a big proportion of the original polygons.
Similar strange results happen using smaller sets (municipalities) (212 in Year 2) (233 in Year 1)

Comment: @Tony Trew I think the problem is the type of geometry you are using maybe your defining one of your layers as multipolygon and not polygon